# getLoginStatus on arbitrary site?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

My app is displays share buttons for various social media services. Sorta similar to ShareThis, if that helps. It is available for download and installation on customer's websites.

I'd like to prominently feature the share buttons that the user is logged in to. For example, I want to show the FB share button at the top if they are logged in to FB.

When I install my app on the same domain as my app's Site URL, a call to getLoginStatus
works great. I can determine if the user has logged in regardless of whether they've given my app permissions.

But when I install my app on a customer's site -- one that's not listed in my app's settings -- getLoginStatus returns this error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application configuration
It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or domain must be the same
as or a subdomain of one of the Application&#039;s base domains.
```

That's not really practical for me, since my app could be installed on thousands of domains, many of which I won't even be aware of.

Is there any way around this? Can I get the user's login status even if I'm running my app on an arbitrary domain?

Thanks a ton for any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any way around this? Can I get the user's login status even if I'm running my app on an arbitrary domain?

**NO**

Just think about the security and privacy issues related with it :) *What damage those annoying pop ups/ ads can do to the web if they can know you are online on facebook :)*

But yes, there's a hack to know login status but its not recommended if you building an app depending on it.

[Check if someone is online on fb/twitter/gmail](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information)

Comment: OK, thanks. Yeah, I don't want to build an app that's going to "break the rules".

Comment: However you can create a fixed page. Tell people to allow your app there.

Now, when you need to check loginstatus, do a jsonp call to your server from any website. The server checks if user is online or not and then can give a response to your app at client side. I've used this approach and it worked for me in past. But its not recommended again :)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don’t think that’s at all possible.